# How to make marker be attached to the ground in Mapbox Android SDK?

Tags: android, mapbox

I am using the latest Mapbox Android SDK and trying to show markers for transport on the map. There is a flag `isFlat` that indicates that the marker should be parallel to the ground. However when I rotate the map the marker doesn't rotate together with the ground, e.g. if I set the rotation angle so, that the marker is facing north, after user rotates the map, the marker will not rotate, and will no longer point to north. This behavior is different from Google Maps SDK I previously used.

I have to manually readjust marker's rotation on each camera update event (when camera rotation changes). The question is how do I fix the marker's position so that it will stick to the ground and rotate together with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we haven't implemented any kind of anchoring to keep the marker pointing it a specific map orientation, the best solution for now would be to add a `onCameraChangeListener` to the map and update the marker when the map's rotated:

```
marker = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerViewOptions()
      .position(new LatLng(40.73581, -73.99155))
      .flat(true));

mapboxMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new MapboxMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
        marker.setRotation((float) -position.bearing);
      }
    });
```

This should adjust the marker orientation each time the maps rotated and keep it pointing in the same direction.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. But I noticed that there is a lag (and perhaps an animation of the marker) after I call `marker.setRotation()`. Is there any way to disable animation?

Comment: Are there any plans to support achoring?

Comment: You can adjust marker anchoring already. See [this example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxandroiddemo/labs/MarkerFollowingRouteActivity.java#L191)